# Fazer um select com opções que serão gravadas e variáveis!

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

Bom dia, eu gostaria de criar um código em que eu tenha um select com varia opções e quando uma delas for selecionada e o usuário dar o submit, a string dessa opção seja passada a uma variável, conseguem me ajudar? no caso do código abaixo eu tentei utilizar o angular porém ainda sou iniciante, pode se usar qualquer linguagem para fazer o select
, obrigado

```html
<form class="form" method="post" action="date.php">

            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <input class="btn" type="submit">
                </div>
                <input type="month" class="form-control" name="datac" value="<?php echo $ano ?>-<?php echo $mes ?>" required>
                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                    <select ng-model="uni">
                        <option value="BRAZIL" ng-selected="uni=='BRAZIL'">BRAZIL</option>
                        <option value="USA" ng-selected="uni == 'USA'">USA</option>
                        <option value="CANADA" ng-selected="uni == 'CANADA'">CANADA</option>
                        <option value="RUSSIA" ng-selected="uni == 'RUSSIA'">RUSSIA</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Você já chegou a dar uma olhada em [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: Não, vou olhar agora

Comment: Olá, não entendi bem a sua dúvida. Você simplesmente quer que o valor selecionado no form seja passado ao servidor?, ou o valor do select ser uma variável do javascript para posterior uso? você já usa o angular em seu projeto ou o inseriu somente para esta funcionalidade?

Comment: tá calma, eu tentei fazer com angular mais não deu certo, esquece a parte do angular, eu quero selecionar uma opção do select e quando dar submit o value desse opção vai para uma variavel php, entendeu?